# iOS how to known the coordinate is correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I am using CLLocationManager to get the location coordinate.

I using

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
  didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
     [locations lastObject]
  ...
}
```

They can get the last location.

But I found if we get the lastObject at the initial.

The location is not really coordinate that will drift.

Over the some time, the coordinate will convergence the point.

But how can I know the value is really at the current place now?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `horizontalAccuracy`and `verticalAccuracy` properties of your `CLLocation` objects in order to know the precision of the measure.

According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/horizontalAccuracy) :

**horizontalAccuracy :**

> The radius of uncertainty for the location, measured in meters.
>   (read-only)
>
> The location’s latitude and longitude
>   identify the center of the circle, and this value indicates the radius
>   of that circle. A negative value indicates that the location’s
>   latitude and longitude are invalid.

**verticalAccuracy :**

> The accuracy of the altitude value in meters. (read-only)
>
> The value in the altitude property could
>   be plus or minus the value indicated by this property. A negative
>   value indicates that the altitude value is invalid.

Just wait for your horizontal value to decrease until a reasonable threshold in order to consider the coordinates exacts.

Comment: ... or as accurate as it is ever going to be!  Don't wait for the uncertainty to reach zero.

Comment: 'The radius of uncertainty for the location' means almost nothing. Thanks iOS documentation. Does anyone know specifically/quantitatively what this means? Probably it is something like "a 68% confidence interval in the location" or something like that. Would be great to know specifically.